# Java chess game: how to check whether a piece is already on the tile?

Tags: java, project, chess, bluej

I´m currently programming my first chess game and I have a small problem with my pieces. I´ll add some of my code below, but generally, I would like to check whether the tile a player moves a certain piece (in this example the king) to, is already occupied by another piece because in that case the other piece would either be killed (if the piece belongs to the other player) or the move would be false (tile occupied by own piece).
If you have any ideas how it could be done, I´d appreciate it greatly.
Best regards

```
public abstract class Piece
{
   
    
    protected int x;
    protected int y;
    protected Tile finalTile;
    protected Type type;
    protected boolean killed;
    protected boolean white;
    
    
    public Piece(boolean white, int x, int y)
    {
        
        this.setWhite(white);
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.finalTile = finalTile;
                
    }
    
    public boolean isWhite() {
        return this.white;
    }
    
    public void setWhite (boolean white) {
        this.white = white;
    }
    
    public boolean isKilled() {
        return this.killed;
    }
    
    public void setKilled (boolean killed) {
        this.killed = killed;
    }
    
    // which type of Piece is being used
    public abstract Type getType();
    
    //is the chosen move valid?
    
      public abstract boolean canMovePiece (Chessboard chessboard, int finalX, int finalY);
    
    //The validation of the move does not show in which direction the piece is being moved. To set 
      the piece at its new spot (tile), a determination of the direction is needed for the 
    // calculation of the new spot on the chessboard

    public abstract void setNewPieceLocation();

}


public class King extends Piece
{

    
    public King(boolean white, int x, int y)
    {
        
        super(white, x, y);
        type = Type.KING;
        
    }

   
    
    public Type getType() {
        return Type.KING;
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean canMovePiece(Chessboard chessboard, int finalX, int finalY) {
        
            
            int x_diff = Math.abs(finalX - this.x);
            int y_diff = Math.abs(finalY - this.y);
            
        //the king can only move one tile per round. The direction does not matter. Therefore, the 
          movements can be either one on the x-axis, the y-axis or one on both. 
        
        if ( x_diff == 1 && y_diff == 0 || x_diff == 0 && y_diff == 1 || x_diff == 1 && y_diff ==1) {
            return true;
        }
            
        }
        
    @Override
    public void setNewPieceLocation() {
        
        int finalX = this.x;
        int finalY = this.y;
    
    }
}
```

Comment: As an aside: why make `getType()` abstract? Just pass the `Type` to the super constructor, and store it in a field there.

Comment: "If you have any ideas how it could be done" you'd need to look at `chessboard`, which doesn't seem to be used, and you've not shown its definition.

Comment: Another aside: the `canMovePiece` condition for the king can be simplified to `Math.max(x_diff, y_diff) <= 1`.

Comment: Here's an idea.  Create an  8 x 8 int array that holds a logical chessboard.  A black pawn is 1, knights are 2, bishops are 3, rooks are 5, the queen is 10 and the king is 20.  The white pieces have similar negative values.  Make your moves on the int array, then use the int array to draw the state of the chessboard.

Comment: Hi @Alice333! If an answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1):

In tile-based computer games, you always have to make a very important initial design decision about what you choose as your central data structure:

1. The field itself, e.g. as a two-dimensional array, where the state of each tile in the field represents which piece is on it or
2. A collection of pieces with coordinates.

Option 1 is great if you have a small field and the pieces can only be directly on a tile.

Option 2 should only be done if option 2 is not possible, i.e.:

- your game world is very large and sparse, e.g. 1 million x 1 million, then you would have an array with one trillion entries or (inclusive or)
- your pieces can be halfway or otherwise fractionally located respectively with the tiles

Option 1 is easiest to implement if there is at most one piece at any one tile at the same time but you can work around that and it would depend on the specific circumstances, which one is best.

Now which case do we have in chess? As an exercise you can think about this yourself but I will give the solution below:

The first option is the perfect fit for chess, because you have a very small field (8x8), the pieces are exactly on the tiles (in theory, even if they may be a few millimeters off in practice) and there can be at most one piece per tile.

Option 1 has the advantage that it becomes extremely easy to check, which piece is on a certain tile: just check the field data structure at that point!

Another very important point for beginners is however how to map your coordinate system to your data structure especially in the case of a two dimensional array. Which dimension of the array is which axis of your game world and in which direction? There is however no right or wrong here, just clearly document it and be consistent!

For example, I personally like to have y going from top to bottom as the first dimension of the array and x going from left to right as field[y][x] because computer graphics memory is aligned that way (at least it was this way in the old 10h 320x200 8 bit palette video mode) but a mathematics teacher may very well prefer x first and y going from bottom to top as field[x][y] because that's how you usually draw 2-dimensional plots and write points with x first in mathematical notation.

So in my mental model, checking the top left would be checking the value field[0][0], top right would be field[0][7], bottom left field[7][0] and bottom right would be field[7][7].

Our hypothetical mathematics teacher could instead use field[0][7] for top left, top right would be field[7][7], bottom left field[0][0] and bottom right would be field[7][0].

Just use what works for you (and your team if you have one).

In order to prevent problems with object equality vs object identity I would not use a class for the type but an enum as that is the perfect fit for this case. As an empty field, you can either use null, but then you may need a bunch of checks to prevent NullPointerException, or you create a special value for an empty field.

Checking, which piece is in a certain spot with option 2 is not hard either, but as option 1 is so much easier here and also faster in case that matters, I will not get into detail about that here as that is not the best solution to your problem.